# How to move domain to new host?

Tags: email, domain, web-hosting, dns-hosting

I am very new to working with domains. Yesterday I set up a domain for my company. I used the service `strato.de`. Now I've read VERY bad customer reviews of this service and am afraid that I made a mistake. Unfortunately I already set up the domain I want `examplecompany.com` for personalized email addresses and email forwarding.

Will I be able to move my domain to another host/service or is it bound to `strato.de`?

Comment: To have a better understanding you should strive to separate two things: the job of a domain registrar (which is to register your domain and then update it per your wishes, including and very importantly to set the nameservers authoritative over it) and the job of a DNS provider (having nameservers configured for your domain and answering queries), and even the job of a web hoster and an email hoster. All 4 of these things can be done by different companies. Or by the same one. But they are different, with different constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be unable to transfer the domain to another registrar within 60 days after initial registration, change of contact information, or transfer. This [ICANN FAQ](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/name-holder-faqs-2017-10-10-en) explains the rules regarding domain transfers.

You can, however, move your web site, email and DNS services at any time. If you plan to transfer the domain, and you have other services at this registrar that you want to move, you should consider moving these and having them already at a new host before you try to transfer the domain name.

Comment: Thank you. I will use this service for email traffic until I need additional services. Then I will move to another registrar.

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov It can be very disruptive to move email service that has been in use for some time. If the domain is new, you might want to move email now, before it has any significant amount of messages or users.

Comment: Thanks again for your insight. I will only use this service for me and my wife, the dns name and email forwarding. So there shouldnt be much work to be done when it needs to be moved.